# sending EOF to stdin in Clion IDE

Tags: c, clion

Is there a way to send EOF to stdin when running a c program in Clion IDE?
I tried ctrl+D - it simply shuts the program down.
Ctrl+Z doesn't work either.
Any ideas?

BTW - I'm using it on a Windows 10 OS.

Comment: In Windows, `Ctrl-Z` must be the *first keystroke after a `newline`*. Don't know about Clion.

Comment: Did you find your answer by any chance, I found out about this the hard way :( no solution yet.

Comment: @gideon I'm afraid not..

Comment: So the console where the output shows, on linux a `CTRL+ D` results in a `SIGHUP` and terminates the program however, if I open the **Terminal and run the program it all works**

Comment: In CLion on MacOS, cmd+D sends EOF and ctrl+D runs the code in Debug.

Answer (score 13):

ctrl+D does the job, however there is a known [problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5704), to avoid it disable option *run.processes.with.pty* in Registry (Find Action > Registry).

Answer (score 6):

Type in ^ on a newline, in the console after your input, I found it does the trick.

Comment: That worked for me aswell, Ubuntu inside VMware

Comment: to clarify, ^ *followed* by newline works for me (using Debian). For more info, see ["Caret notation" on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to run the program from command line, and attach to it from CLion.
In that case, you'll have your native shell.

It's detailed at 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/01/attach-to-local-process/

The process is very simple - after running the program from command line, choose Run->Attach to Local Process...

And choose your program from the list. You can type in the search field.