CLion - Triggering EOF During Input (Run Window)
I asked a question in the below link regarding how/when EOF triggers a simple C program to finish execution and output a count of characters using getchar().
Triggering EOF From Keyboard Input (Terminal)
Here's the code from that question:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double nc;

    for (nc = 0; getchar() !=EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}

When I run this in CLion, I'm able to input characters, but no matter what I try, I cannot seem to trigger the EOF to end the program and output the count.  I've tried every possible combination of Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+D, Ctrl+C, ESC, Enter, etc.  In every case I have to manually stop the program and I get no output.

Is there any way to trigger this EOF from within the run window?

Thank you for any help!

Try looking at the terminal settings, there might be an option for what it's specified as. For MacOS I think it's -D, for Windows you might need -Z, or it might be something else.

You could also try selecting "Run in external console" in the run configuration - I found that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405577/sending-eof-to-stdin-in-clion-ide

Thanks @JohnBayko.  In messing around searching for those options (never did find 'em), I ended up running the program in the embedded Terminal window (as opposed to the Run window) and I seem to get the same functionality as the Windows Terminal, which allows me to conclude the program with a ^Z.  It's more work, but at least I don't need to leave CLion.
